# Xmas Maths 2014

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics

Inspired the various** algebraic X'mas greetings sent to me over the festive period, I thought I would try to devise one of my own.

$$\Large \color{red}{\sum_{i=a-1}^{r-1}}\color{green}{\sum_{j=s-1}^{r-1}}\color{orange}{\binom {e-x}{m-x}}\color{red}{\binom ex}\color{orange}{ \binom i{a-1}}\color{green}{\binom j{s-1}}\color{red}{\binom y{\prod_{k=1}^{2014}k}}\\
$$

The colours are purely ornamental!

** *Actually there were only two versions: one was an equation with a $\ln$ function and the other required knowledge of Newton's second law; both of these have popped up in various places on web as well.*

Comment: Nice ! (+1) Merry Christmas and *good-luck* with it :)

Comment: @r9m - Thanks and Merry Xmas!

Comment: Should that first sum be from $i = a-1$ to $r-1$ instead of $r=1$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - Yes, that's right - thanks! Amended.

Comment: Why put everything in `\large` and even in `\Large`?

Comment: For added clarity because it's a "four-tier" equation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

$$\large\begin{align}
& \color{red}{\sum_{i=a-1}^{r-1}}\color{green}{\sum_{j=s-1}^{r-1}}
\color{orange}{\binom {e-x}{m-x}}\color{red}{\binom ex}\color{orange}{ \binom i{a-1}}
\color{green}{\binom j{s-1}}\color{red}{\binom y{\prod_{k=1}^{2014}k}}\\
&=\color{orange}{\binom {e-x}{m-x}}\color{red}{\binom ex}\color{red}{\binom y{\prod_{k=1}^{2014}k}}\color{red}{\sum_{i=a-1}^{r-1}}
\color{orange}{ \binom i{a-1}}\color{green}{\sum_{j=s-1}^{r-1}}\color{green}{\binom j{s-1}}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom ex}\color{orange}{\binom {e-x}{m-x}}
\color{red}{\binom y{\prod_{k=1}^{2014}k}}\color{orange}{ \binom ra}\color{green}{\binom rs}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom em}\color{orange}{\binom mx}\color{red}{\binom y{2014!}}
\color{orange}{ \binom ra}\color{green}{\binom rs}\\
&=\color{orange}{\binom mx}\color{red}{\binom em}\color{orange}{ \binom ra}
\color{green}{\binom rs}\color{red}{\binom y{2014!}}
\end{align}$$

Merry Xmas, everyone!!!

Comment: It's times like this that I realise I don't have a clue what's going on and that I really don't belong here.

Comment: @Pharap - You just have to read the last line of the equation! :)