# New Year Maths 2015

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, products

In the spirit of the festive period and in appreciation of the encouraging response to my [Xmas Combinatorics 2014](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081270/xmas-combinatorics) problem posted recently, here's one for the New Year!

> Express the following as a product of four binomial coefficients:
>   $$\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{M-1}r}\color{orange}{\sqrt{\int_0^X 2x dx}}
> \color{green}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{120}(V!-i+1) \right)}
> \color{indigo}{\left(\prod_{h=1}^Mh\right)}
> \left[\color{maroon}{\left(\prod_{n=1}^{120}n\right)}\color{blue}{\left(\prod_{y=1}^M y\right)}\right]^{-1} $$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{M-1}r}{\color{orange}{\sqrt{\int_0^X 2x dx}}}
\color{green}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{120}(V!-i+1) \right)}
\color{indigo}{\left(\prod_{h=1}^Mh\right)}
\left[\color{maroon}{\left(\prod_{n=1}^{120}n\right)}
\color{blue}{\left(\prod_{y=1}^M y\right)}\right]^{-1} \\\\
&=\color{orange}{\sqrt{\int_0^X 2x dx}}
\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{M-1}r}
\color{green}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{120}(V!-i+1) \right)}
\color{indigo}{\left(\prod_{h=1}^Mh\right)}
\left[\color{maroon}{\left(\prod_{n=1}^{120}n\right)}
\color{blue}{\left(\prod_{y=1}^M y\right)}\right]^{-1} \\\\
&=\color{orange}{\sqrt{\left[{x^2}\right]_0^X}}\cdot 
\color{red}{\frac{M(M-1)}2}\cdot 
\color{green}{V!^{\underline{120}}}
\color{indigo}{M!}
\left[\color{maroon}{120!}\color{blue}{M!}\right]^{-1} \\\\
&=\color{orange}X\cdot 
\color{red}{\frac{M(M-1)}2}\cdot 
\color{green}{V!^{\underline{120}}}
\color{indigo}{M!}
\left[\color{maroon}{120!}\color{blue}{M!}\right]^{-1} \\\\
&=\color{orange}{\frac X1}\cdot 
\color{red}{\frac{M(M-1)}{1\cdot 2}}\cdot
\color{green}{\frac{V!^{\underline{120}}}{\color{maroon}{120!}}}\cdot 
\color{indigo}{\frac{M!}{\color{blue}{M!}}}\\\\
&=\color{orange}{\binom X1}
\color{red}{\binom M2}
\color{green}{\binom {V!}{120}}
\color{indigo}{\binom MM}\\\\
&=\color{red}{\binom M2}
\color{indigo}{\binom M0}
\color{orange}{\binom X1}
\color{green}{\binom {V!}{5!}}\\\\ \\\\
\end{align}$$

Happy New Year!

Comment: Awesome!!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $24 = 5!{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: I shall frame this one ! Thanks and Happy New Year !!

Comment: @peterwhy - Thanks! Amended :)

Comment: I saw the Merry X-mas one too !! :-) How do you think of these brilliant identities ? :D

Comment: Thanks for your kind and generous comments, everyone! Happy New Year!!

Comment: @sciona - I can't say for certain, but it's probably just "reverse engineering". Start with the final line, input the definition and manipulate it backwards. :) Still good though! =D